# method not declared when using library built from source

Tags: c++, makefile

I am trying to build an app written in C++ with make. I get this error when building the app:

```
/fake/path/ZK_session.cpp: In function 'blah::ZK_result blah::base_create(zhandle_t*, const string&, const string&, const string&, int)':

/fake/path/ZK_session.cpp:202:22: error: '::zoo_create' has not been declared

         auto res = ::zoo_create(zk,

                      ^~~~~~~~~~
```

I know this error has to do with the fact that I am using a version of the Zookeeper client library that I built from source. On a different OS, I used a pre-built binary of the library and didn't get this error.

I am confused why I am getting the message `'::zoo_create' has not been declared` , since Zk_session.h has `#include <zookeeper/zookeeper.h>` , and zookeeper.h does declare the `zoo_create()` method.

**Update:** I wonder if the error has to do with `#ifdef THREADED` in zookeeper.h? Although, I don't see why THREADED would not be defined, since I am using zookeeper_mt, which is the multi-threaded version of the client.

**Zk_session.h**:

```
#ifndef BLAH_BLAH_ZK_ZK_SESSION_H
#define BLAH_BLAH_ZK_ZK_SESSION_H

#include <functional>
#include <map>
#include <mutex>
#include <fake/path/core.h>
#include <string>
#include <zookeeper/zookeeper.h>

namespace blah
{

...

class ZK_session
{
...
}
}

#endif
```

**Zk_session.cpp**:

```
#include <fake/path/ZK_session.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

#include <iostream>

namespace blah
{
...
ZK_result base_create(::zhandle_t* zk,
                      const std::string& node_path,
                      const std::string& leaf_node_value,
                      const std::string& parent_nodes_value,
                      int leaf_node_type = 0)
{
   ...
        std::string node_str {};
   ...
        bool is_leaf = ss.peek() == std::char_traits<char>::eof();
        auto& value = is_leaf ? leaf_node_value : parent_nodes_value;
        auto type = is_leaf ? leaf_node_type : 0; 
   ...
        auto res = ::zoo_create(zk,
                                node_str.c_str(),
                                value.data(),
                                static_cast<int>(value.size()),
                                &ZOO_OPEN_ACL_UNSAFE,
                                type,
                                nullptr,
                                0);
       ...
    return ZK_result{};
}
...
}
```

**[zookeeper.h](https://github.com/apache/zookeeper/blob/master/zookeeper-client/zookeeper-client-c/include/zookeeper.h)**:

```
#ifndef ZOOKEEPER_H_
#define ZOOKEEPER_H_

#include <stdlib.h>

/* we must not include config.h as a public header */
#ifndef WIN32
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#endif

#ifdef WIN32
#include <winsock2.h> /* must always be included before ws2tcpip.h */
#include <ws2tcpip.h> /* for struct sock_addr and socklen_t */
#endif

#ifdef HAVE_OPENSSL_H
#include <openssl/ossl_typ.h>
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#ifdef HAVE_CYRUS_SASL_H
#include <sasl/sasl.h>
#endif /* HAVE_CYRUS_SASL_H */

#include "proto.h"
#include "zookeeper_version.h"
#include "recordio.h"
#include "zookeeper.jute.h"

...

#ifdef THREADED
/**
 * \brief create a node synchronously.
 *
 * This method will create a node in ZooKeeper. A node can only be created if
 * it does not already exist. The Create Mode affects the creation of nodes.
 * If ZOO_EPHEMERAL mode is chosen, the node will automatically get removed if the
 * client session goes away. If ZOO_CONTAINER flag is set, a container node will be
 * created. For ZOO_*_SEQUENTIAL modes, a unique monotonically increasing
 * sequence number is appended to the path name. The sequence number is always fixed
 * length of 10 digits, 0 padded.
 *
 * \param zh the zookeeper handle obtained by a call to \ref zookeeper_init
 * \param path The name of the node. Expressed as a file name with slashes
 * separating ancestors of the node.
 * \param value The data to be stored in the node.
 * \param valuelen The number of bytes in data. To set the data to be NULL use
 * value as NULL and valuelen as -1.
 * \param acl The initial ACL of the node. The ACL must not be null or empty.
 * \param mode this parameter should be one of the Create Modes.
 * \param path_buffer Buffer which will be filled with the path of the
 *    new node (this might be different than the supplied path
 *    because of the ZOO_SEQUENCE flag).  The path string will always be
 *    null-terminated. This parameter may be NULL if path_buffer_len = 0.
 * \param path_buffer_len Size of path buffer; if the path of the new
 *    node (including space for the null terminator) exceeds the buffer size,
 *    the path string will be truncated to fit.  The actual path of the
 *    new node in the server will not be affected by the truncation.
 *    The path string will always be null-terminated.
 * \return  one of the following codes are returned:
 * ZOK operation completed successfully
 * ZNONODE the parent node does not exist.
 * ZNODEEXISTS the node already exists
 * ZNOAUTH the client does not have permission.
 * ZNOCHILDRENFOREPHEMERALS cannot create children of ephemeral nodes.
 * ZBADARGUMENTS - invalid input parameters
 * ZINVALIDSTATE - zhandle state is either ZOO_SESSION_EXPIRED_STATE or ZOO_AUTH_FAILED_STATE
 * ZMARSHALLINGERROR - failed to marshall a request; possibly, out of memory
 */
ZOOAPI int zoo_create(zhandle_t *zh, const char *path, const char *value,
        int valuelen, const struct ACL_vector *acl, int mode,
        char *path_buffer, int path_buffer_len);

...
#endif

...

#endif
```

Comment: You have been on this site long enough to know about [minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Added some code for context.

Comment: Regardless of how the _library_ was compiled, are you defining `THREADED` when you include the header?

Comment: @Botje So, I added `#define THREADED 1` before the `#ifdef THREADED` line in zookeeper.h, but that didn't change anything.

Comment: Oops, I was editing the wrong version of zookeeper.h. `#define THREADED 1` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `zoo_create()` function in zookeeper.h was surrounded by an `#ifdef THREADED` block, I just added `#define THREADED 1` before the start of the block, and that fixed the issue.